# Is there a way to prevent an insert via query on a SQL database by showing an error message ( Java) before I hit the HTTP 500 error page?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, message

Constraint code that I wrote to say if the edited date is not within this range then displays an error message before the 500 error page.

```java
    Project project = new Project();

    public boolean validateStartDate1(MessageContext msgContext, Station station, Project project) {
        boolean valid = true;

        if (!station.getProjectDate().after(project.getEndDate())) {
            msgContext.addMessage(new MessageBuilder().error().source("projectDate")
                    .code("station.invalidEndDate").build());
            valid = false;
        }
        if (!station.getProjectDate().before(project.getStartDate())) {
            msgContext.addMessage(new MessageBuilder().error().source("projectDate")
                    .code("station.invalidStartDate").build());
            valid = false;
        }
        return valid;
    }
```

And the flow file in which I call the function validateStartDate1 in an xml file.

```xml
<view-state id="stationform" view="/stationForm2.xhtml" model="station">

    <transition on="save" validate="true" to="newStnMaintRpt">
        <evaluate expression="stationFormFlowActions.saveStationEdit(station, messageContext)"/>
        <evaluate expression="stationFormFlowActions.validateStartDate1(msgContext, station, project)"/>
    </transition>
```

The error message I want it to display when they select and try to save the edits. In a properties file.

```
station.invalidEndDate=Start date must be prior assigned project end date.
station.invalidStartDate=Start date must be after the assigned project start date.
```

The error I get as of now when I proceed to save with an incorrect date.

[image: Error message]
[image: Error message]
[image: Error message]
[image: Error message]

Comment: Well a couple ways come quickly to mind where you actually put the constraint **in the data base**. That way the requirement is satisfied even if the values are set outside of your application. This can be done with check constraints (preferred) or triggers. But without table definition(s) that is as far I can go now. If you want to peruse this process post your table(s) DDL.

Comment: Yes, I wrote a check constraint and called a different instance. That seemed to do the trick. Thank you Belayer.                                                                                                                    @AssertTrue
 private boolean validateProjectDate() {
  if (projectDate.before(this.stationProject.getStartDate()))  {
   return false;
  }

  if (projectDate.after(this.stationProject.getEndDate())) {
   return false;
  }

  return true;
 }

Comment: '''public boolean validateStartDate(MessageContext messages, Station station) {
  boolean valid = true;

  if (!station.getProjectDate().after(station.getStationProject().getEndDate())) {
   messages.addMessage(new MessageBuilder().error().source("projectDate")
     .code("station.invalidEndDate").build());
   valid = false;
  }
  return valid;
 }'''